# Поиск строк в массиве по уменьшению их кол-ства

Tags: c#

Вопрос таков: имеется `.txt` файл в качестве массива, в нем прописано 20 строк. Строки разные и разной длинны. Или же лучше прописать массив прямо в код ? типа

```
string array ={"1-я строка из тхт","2-я строка из тхт",..."посл. строка из тхт"};
```

как прописать код, который будет в `.txt` или в самом в коде искать строки **по очереди** ? Надо чтобы одно значение из массива искал только один раз, а не по многу..Если совсем коротко, одно значение из массива искать без повторений, то есть один раз нашел в массиве, все, больше его не ищет..примерно так.

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Попробуйте его перефразировать.

Comment: @118_64 вопрос переформулировал

Comment: Что значит искать? По каким признакам? Заведите `Dictionary<string, int>`, где ключами будут Ваши строки, а значениями - их индексы в массиве.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно, понял, то вы хотите исключить уже найденную строку из последующих поисков.

Тогда вам стоит отказать от массивов в пользу `List<string>`.

Работа с ним подобна массивам, но список- это динамическая структура => можно менять его размерность удаляя элементы.

Нашли нужны элемент? Выполните `RemoveAt(index)` и больше вы его не найдете.

**UPD**

Пример через метод расширения:

```
public static class ListExtension
{
    public static T GetAndDelete<T>(this List<T> listToFind, T valueToFind)
    {
        var index = listToFind.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(valueToFind));
        var result = listToFind[index];
        listToFind.RemoveAt(index);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
  var list = new List<string>() { "123", "321" };
            var result = list.GetAndDelete("123");
```

Имейте в виду, что если коллекция большая, то имеет смысл использовать HashSet, который более эффективен в плане поиска. Переделать код не составит труда.

Comment: можете написать примерные код ?

Comment: @Rolly готово..

Comment: Прописывать надо самому вот этот "123", а как этот процесс автоматизировать? Мол, нашел, сам удалил, без прописки, без участия юзера ?

Comment: А что вы искать собрались? Может я не понял задачу? Вы пишите про поиск, а как вы собираетесь искать если не будете что-либо вводить? Кто инициализирует поиск?

Comment: Хотел уточнить одну вещь! Вы спросили "А что вы искать собрались?"....ответ в первой строке вопроса: "массив, в нем прописано 20 строк" то есть строки, и тут такая "непонятка" а именно, если в `.txt` прописать строки, пусть даже циферные строки ,все равно `124124` ,`9878` ,`12` ,`90`...пример строк, то есть нашлась такая же строка, то он, код, будет ее по новой искать  или же надо функцию Вашу юзать, которая выполняет поиск строк без повтора ?

Comment: @Rolly. "Нашлась такая же строка". Вы имеете в виду, что в массиве, который ведете поиск есть дубли или имете в виду, что одну и туже строчку можете искать в целевом массиве в разное время? Если второе, то мой метод удаляет строчку, после нахождения в месте ге вы ищите.

Comment: именно так, "мой метод удаляет строчку, после нахождения в месте ге вы ищите" пусть строка будет лучше ее через массив все таки, но если она нашлась то ее пусть больше не ищет, так будет получше :)

Comment: Если не удалят найденную строку в массиве то эту строка просто не вписывать в код ? `listToFind.RemoveAt(index);`

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь операцией Linq [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (var s in array.Distinct())
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Будут выведены только уникальные записи, все повторяющиеся будут пропущены.

Comment: "Строки разные и разной длинны."

Comment: @Igor, я думаю, автор сам еще не понял чего он хочет