# Повторный вопрос с уточнением

Tags: c#

Недавно задавал такой вопрос на счет списка строк:
[Поиск строк в массиве по уменьшению их кол-ства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764254/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Там написан код, который удаляет найденный строки, но по сути, нужно не много иначе, а именно, когда нашел строку (в процессе простого перебора), которая совпадает с элементом в списке, то код этот элемент в списке не удаляет, просто игнорит его (больше не ищет, если по новой он попался), как только софт нашел все элементы, содержащиеся в списке (`012`,`234`), то он завершает свою работу...в сети искал, примерный ответ хотябы, безуспешно..//все не то..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> digits = new List<string>(new string[] { "012","234"});
        string alfabet = "0123456789";
        for (int a = 0; a < alfabet.Length; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < alfabet.Length; b++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < alfabet.Length; c++)
                {
                    string abc = alfabet[a].ToString() + alfabet[b].ToString() + alfabet[c].ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(abc);
                    //здесь нужен код, который будет выполнять действия..только вот проблема с его реализацией.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> digits = new List<string>(new string[] { "012","234"});
    int counter = 0;
    string alfabet = "0123456789";
    for (int a = 0; a < alfabet.Length && counter < digits.Count; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < alfabet.Length && counter < digits.Count; b++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < alfabet.Length && counter < digits.Count; c++)
            {
                string abc = alfabet[a].ToString() + alfabet[b].ToString() + alfabet[c].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(abc);


    //если starts или endswith элементы в списке:
//foreach (var items in digits)
                        //{
                        //    if (abc.EndsWith(items))
                        //   {
                if (digits.IndexOf(abc) >= 0)
                {
                    counter++;
                    Console.WriteLine("found, total = " + counter.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Прописав такое условие, что если посл. два знака от строк, кончаются с `12`, и `34`, то что-то не выходит вот так `if (abc.StartsWith(digits))`//где тут может быть ошибка, вроде логично //написал ? Все что не кончается с этих чисел, не надо показывать..

Comment: `String.StartsWith`: параметр - строка. Вы подаете туда `List<string>`. Компилироваться не будет. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx